# Restore change set

Tags: change-set, undelete

Is there any way to restore a deleted change set? Unfortunately I haven't found it in the recycle bin. I have also found no setting or other location to restore / undelete them.

Comment: Do you still have the change set in the sandbox that it was sent from?  You can clone it and re-send.  That assumes no changes have been made in those components in the sandbox since the last send.

Comment: That is what I exactly don't have... - already deleted it in the sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a Change Set has been deleted in the environment it originates in then it is not possible to recreate it or clone it.

Unfortunately this means the only way to reproduce it is to manually create a new Change Set in the relevant source environment. It will be possible to see what has been included if the Change Set still exists in the target environment, but this will not give any options to clone this to send to another target environment.

[Change sets best practices](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_best_practices.htm&language=en) and [Implementation Tips](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_implementation_notes.htm&language=en_US)